# Логика аутентификации приложения и сайта

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, tcp

Существует сайт, для которого я решил сделать(и научиться) приложение через Qt. Я не понимаю логики, через которую все нужно реализовать. Я примерно понял путь, но насколько он правильный - не знаю. Пока хочу сделать так, чтобы все сработало, OAuth/secure пока не разбираю, это уже на потом.

1. Необходимо запарсить **https** на html.
2. Объединить LineEdit(логин/пароль) с формой на сайте и провести процесс.(но опять же, мне кажется, что это абсолютный бред, так как я не передам данные на сервер, а просто введу строку в строку...)
3. Проверка на правильность, произошла ли авторизация(опять же, я не понимаю как это нужно производить)
4. Обработка профиля через тот-же парсер. Вытягивать открытые данные профиля(фото профиля, имя и т.д.)

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала нужно изучить, какие вообще [способы веб-аутентификации](https://habr.com/ru/company/dataart/blog/262817/) существуют.

Затем прочитать про модуль `Qt` [network](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-index.html).

В частности обратить внимание на `QAuthenticator`, который как раз отвечает за аутентификацию на сайтах.

Небольшой quick-start для медитации:

```
QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
QNetworkRequest request{ QUrl{"https://pornhub.com"} };
QNetworkReply* reply = manager->post(request, "big tits");
reply->ignoreSslErrors();

QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::authenticationRequired,
                 [=](QNetworkReply* reply, QAuthenticator * authenticator)
{
    qDebug() << "Выполняется аутентификация";
    authenticator->setUser("v.pupkin");
    authenticator->setPassword("P@ssw0rd");
});

QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, [=](QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug() << "Ответ";
    if (reply->error()) {
        qDebug() << "Ошибка" << reply->errorString();
        return;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Обычно для авторизации в приложениях используют access token. При авторизации на сервер отправляется пароль с логином с помощью https/http запроса. Сервер проверяет их, и отдает access token, обычно он отправляет еще срок действия токена, и refresh token
Подробнее читать тут:
https://habr.com/ru/company/Voximplant/blog/323160/
Также прийдется писать скрипты которые будут отдавать даные в нужном формате, например json /xml.
При каждом запросе к сервису надо проверять access token

Comment: Благодарю, уточнение на будущее - если сайт вообще не реализован на поддержку приложения, токен все равно будет выдаваться? Или это уже нужно будет просить реализовать?

Comment: для этого прийдется писать API...